# Setting Up a Leave Plan Table in PeopleSoft 9.1

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm challenged with a Leave Table setup issue and would like some guidance.

Background: I have a division at work where they do not accumulate any vacation time on their first year of service. All the accrued vacation time are backloaded and you receive the hours the following calendar year based on the previous year's service. I am having issues setting up the accrual service for the First Year Award Values because when I try to set the "Month Eligible" field to 13, it gives me an error. Screenshots can be provided or I can try to explain this better. But I'm up for any suggestions since I have a test environment to play around with this setup

Example 1:

```
DOH = jan 1, 2015 on Jan 1, 2016; member would accrue 10 days based on the service from Jan 1, 2015 to Dec 31, 2015 on Jan 1, 2017; member would accrue 10 days based on the service from Jan 1, 2016 to Dec 31, 2016
```

The breakdown for the 1st year of service is prorated based on month of hire:

Example 2:

```
DOH = feb 1, 2015 on Jan 1, 2016; member would accrue 9 days based on the service from Feb 1, 2015 to Dec 31, 2015 on Jan 1, 2017; member would accrue 10 days based on the service from Jan 1, 2016 to Dec 31, 2016
```

Example 3:

```
DOH = mar 1, 2015 on Jan 1, 2016; member would accrue 8 days based on the service from Feb 1, 2015 to Dec 31, 2015 on Jan 1, 2017; member would accrue 10 days based on the service from Jan 1, 2016 to Dec 31, 2016
```

with continuing the breakdown until the 12th month.

Example 4:

```
DOH = dec 1, 2015 on Jan 1, 2016; member would accrue 0 days based on the service from Dec 1, 2015 to Dec 31, 2015 on Jan 1, 2017; member would accrue 10 days based on the service from Jan 1, 2016 to Dec 31, 2016
```

Will this be part of the "Special Calculation Routine" checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the ***Service Calc at Year Begin*** box instead.  That will calculate leave accruals based on service as of Jan. 1 of the current year.  For the accrual setup, try the following:

**Service Units** = Months

**Accrual Rate Units** = Hours per Year (Award Frequency = First Run of Year)

**First Year Award Values** ==> ***NOT USED***

**Accrual Rate Values** (You did not indicate subsequent years, so you may need more intervals.)

```
After Service Interval    Accrue Hours At
13 Service Months         10 Hours per Year
```

**Service Bonus Values** (Assuming no accrual if hired after October)

```
After Service Interval    Award Bonus Hours
 3 Service Months         1.000000 
 4 Service Months         1.000000 
 5 Service Months         1.000000 
 6 Service Months         1.000000 
 7 Service Months         1.000000 
 8 Service Months         1.000000 
 9 Service Months         1.000000 
10 Service Months         1.000000 
11 Service Months         1.000000 
12 Service Months         1.000000
```

The SBV's + Svc Calc @ Yr Begin should cover your first year requirement, but you may need to tweak the setup if I did not understand it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, it'd never occur to me that I could use "Service Bonus Values" to handle this situation.

I'll have to play around with this setup in my test environment and report back with my testing results

Comment: Hi,  
I got confused with this setup, here's the breakdown I need to setup but i'm not sure how to duplicate that into the SBVs:  
    
- hired in Jan accrue 10 days
- hired in Feb accrue 9 days  
- hired in Mar accrue 8 days
- hired in Apr accrue 7 days
- hired in May accrue 6 days
- hired in June & July accrue 5 days
- hired in Aug accrue 4 days
- hired in Sept accrue 3 days
- hired in Oct accrue 2 days
- hired in Nov accrue 1 day
- hired in Dec accrue 0 days

any help is appreciated